# bytes casted to int by a list constructor

Tags: python, types, casting

I want to read *n* bytes a binary file and store each byte in a list. However, when I do so, each byte is casted into an `int`.

First I create a random file.

```
$ head -c 16 > random.file
```

Then I try to read it:

```py
>>> with open('random.file', 'rb') as fp:
...     l = list(fp.read(8))
...     print(fp.read(8))
... 
b'@\xc2\xdf\x9f\xbbv\xa1\x90'
>>> l
[79, 233, 19, 116, 252, 50, 248, 144]
>>> type(l[0])
<class 'int'>
```

So I understand that my byte value cannot go over `255` however the fact that Python is automatically casting is causing issues since don't get the expected type.

Is that normal? How can I avoid this?

Comment: I don't think Python is converting anything. The interpreter is simply showing the decimal values of the byte array

Comment: What would be the point of a list of single-byte `bytes` objects? Do you really need that? Might not be supported because it's a rare use case...

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any single byte you access in a list of bytes is just a single int value:

```
>>> b"foo"[0]
102
```

If you want to create a new list that consists of lists of bytes with the length 1, you'll have to do that explicitly:

```
>>> c = b"foo"
>>> l = []
>>> for i in range(0, len(c)):
...   l.append(c[i:i+1])
>>> l
[b'f', b'o', b'o']
```

But I'm not really sure I see any reason for doing that, as accessing the single values, which is now embedded inside a new list, will just, again, return an int.

Comment: Well I think you're right. My use case was to have a sliding window on the file so I add one byte at the right and remove one at the left as I progress in the file.